# SNMP Find correct OID to get specific port data from FA-EXT-MIB

Tags: networking, snmp, snmpwalk

I want to fetch data from FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.

Is there any way to snmpwalk this OID (1.3.6.1.4.1.1588.2.1.1.1.28.1.1.5) for a specific port?

Looking at the output (added below) I do not understand the "'....q.......'.1" part of this output.

Is it possible to use this to reference a single port?

This OID gives me :

```
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.1 = STRING: "-2.6" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.2 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.3 = STRING: "-2.8" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.4 = STRING: "-2.6" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.5 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.6 = STRING: "-2.6" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.7 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.8 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.9 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.10 = STRING: "-2.8" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.11 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.12 = STRING: "-2.6" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.13 = STRING: "-2.8" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.14 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.15 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.16 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.17 = STRING: "-2.6" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.18 = STRING: "-2.5" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.19 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.20 = STRING: "-2.6" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.21 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.22 = STRING: "-2.6" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.23 = STRING: "-2.7" dBm
FA-EXT-MIB::swSfpTxPower.'....q.......'.24 = STRING: "-3.0" dBm
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to find the correct OID was simply to use the flag -On to just show the entire OID numerically.

Port0(1) is:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.1588.2.1.1.1.28.1.1.4.16.0.136.148.113.149.167.221.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1
```

Port1(2) is:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.1588.2.1.1.1.28.1.1.4.16.0.136.148.113.149.167.221.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2
```

Etc.